# In Xcode how can I permanently set a file type?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode7

Xcode doesn't recognise `.inl` files as C++ headers. It is annoying to have to set the type in the right sidebar every time I generate a project (as well as having to close the file and re-open it). Is there a way I can do this *permanently*?

Answer (score 0):

In the Finder do the following:

1. Right click on the file name. (in your case a .inl file)
2. Choose the "Get Info" option.
3. Choose "Xcode" from the Open With drop down menu. This will now be set as the permanent default application.

Comment: That just gets Xcode to open the file, which I have set up already. What I want is for Xcode to know that the .inl file is a C++ header so that syntax highlighting works.